# Laravel Login using email instead of username

Tags: laravel

I've custom username table structure:
UserId | Login | Password

I've created my own class User extends Eloquent 
and everything works fine (login and I can create a user in my prepared statement) except posting fields in register form. I've got:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` = some@mail.com)
```

I've searched a lot of forums, but **I haven't created Migration** for my custom columns. Is it required or can I fix it in some other way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to log in using a `email`. But you don't have a `email` field on your database.

To work the way you want (`user` and `password`) you have to change the **email** to **user**.

```
if (Auth::attempt(array('user' => $user, 'password' => $password))) 
{
    return Redirect::intended('dashboard');
}
```

just find where you're making the authentication (probably on `app/routes.php`) and change it.

If you can't find where change it, put some code from filters and from your controller, so we be able to help you more!

=D

Comment: Thanks Dennis, 
I know that, auhtentication works fine.
I've got problem with registering new user posted data. 
While I'm using User::create everything works fine.
But the problem appear with posted data.

Have i use a Migration to automatically update app structure?

Comment: The problem is with 

$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

It genereates query to wrong column.

Comment: I found the answer:

    $rules = array(
            'email'     => 'Required|Between:3,64|Email|Unique:users,Login',
    );

It was:

> Unique:users,**Login**'

Comment: I didn't understood what you said. Anyway, either accept my asnwer or make a new correct one, plz. =D

Comment: I forget about adding a table name to the validate rule ;)
thanks Dennis for your help! :)